Finding the Radius and Interval of Convergence for a Power Series
Question:
Hello, I'm currently studying power series in my calculus class and I've come across a problem that I'm having trouble with. I'm trying to find the radius of convergence and the interval of convergence for the following power series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n!x^n$$
My Attempt:
I know that to find the radius of convergence, I need to use the Ratio Test, which involves taking the limit as n approaches infinity of the absolute value of the ratio of the (n+1)th term to the nth term of the series. However, when I try to apply this to the given series, I end up with:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)!x^{n+1}}{n!x^n}\right|$$
This simplifies to:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|(n+1)x\right|$$
And this is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to proceed from here to find the radius of convergence.
My Background:
I'm an undergraduate student currently enrolled in a calculus course. I have a basic understanding of sequences and series, and I'm familiar with the concepts of convergence and divergence. I've been studying from the textbook "Calculus: Early Transcendentals" by James Stewart.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

In your class you certainly developped a general method to determine the radius of convergence of a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$. This depends only on the sequence $(a_n)$.
Of course you cam also apply the ratio test to see that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^n$ diverges for all $x \ne 0$.
You have $L_x = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)!x^{n+1}}{n!x^n}\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|(n+1)x\right| = (\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)) \left|x\right| = \infty$ for all $x \ne 0$, in particular $L_x > 1$.
The ratio test says that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^n$ diverges for $L_x > 1$.
